# Regex to check if file does not have an extension

Tags: java, regex

I want to process files based on file extension. I need to process 2 files: one is with `.nc` extension and another file with does not have any extension

File name could be anything, doesn't matter.

[image]

for .nc extension I have **.*.nc** regex but I need combine regex. I googled but unable to find anything. Could anyone help me with regex which matches these 2 conditions?

Comment: Could you clarify what you want ? You want a regex that will match this 2 files ? Then you don't care about the extension since it's not the same. How do you exclude other files ? Or you want to look for the file having `.nc` as extension and get it + the file having the same name but without the extension ?

Comment: I have to process files which has extension of .nc or file without extension. It can be of same name or different name. In above screenshot both files has same name but 1 has extension and other has not. It can be either.

Comment: To make it clear, you d'ont care about the name of the file. You want the files that has  `.nc` extension  or files that don't have extension. And all the other files ( = files with extension and extension different from `.nc`) has to be ignored. Am I correct ? Could you edit your question to make it clearer ?

Comment: Yes, correct. I don't care about file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this pattern `(?(?=.*\.)^.*\.nc$|^.*$)`

This is conditional with positive lookahead, which checks if string contains dot (with pattern `(?=.*\.)`). If it does, then match string with `.nc` extension (with `^.*\.nc$`), if not, then match whole string (with `^.*$`).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xzQrRN/1)

Comment: What about this one `(^\w+\.nc$)|(^\w+$)` ? (I'm not an expert of regex that's why I'm asking)

Comment: Well, it might work if you want to match only letters or digits or underscore. It matches any letter, digit or underscore. Equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_].

Comment: Hi vincrichaud, Your expression also worked. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Michal, Thanks for your solution. This expression worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex `(\w+.nc\b|\b\w+\b[^.])`. It would capture anything like `abc.nc` and `abc` but **not** `abc.rc` So it would only capture the required extention or with no extension.

Comment: Have you tried it? It matches `abc-.xyz` but not `a-b.nc`

Comment: Will you be having such file names? @Toto

Comment: Then probably, '([^\s]+.nc|^.[^.]+$)' would suit your requirement I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would also do just fine for your case.
^([^\s]+.nc|[^\s.]+)$
.^and$ asserts position at the start and end of line respectively and in between it matches any word character without extension or with .nc extension.