# Regex to check for certain extensions or no extension and is only 0-9, a-z and hyphens

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex expression to only match certain filenames and extensions.

The filename may or may not have an extension e.g. test and test.txt are valid, but if it does have an extension then it must be limited to certain ones e.g. only .txt or .md but only those 2. It also needs to just be limited to a-z and 0-9 and hyphens/dashes, but should not end with a dash.

Not sure it helps but I've listed some valid and invalid ones below.  I'm using an an existing regex that works fine without extensions - `^([a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)$` but as soon as I bring extensions into it I can't seem to find a solution. I looked at several answers and [Regex to check if file does not have an extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55040365/regex-to-check-if-file-does-not-have-an-extension) is close but this allows characters are aren't a-z or 0-9 or hyphens and I couldn't work out how to correct it.

**Valid/matching**
test
test.txt
test.md
test-one
test-one.md

**Invalid/non-matching**
test.jpg
test_one
test_one.jpeg
test-

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(\.(md|txt))?$` Your regex is well-formed, just need to add an optional group for the extensions. Depending on the language, you may also be able to shorten this regex like this: `^[^\W_]+(-[^\W_]+)*(\.(md|txt))?$` or `^[a-z\d]+(-[a-z\d]+)*(\.(md|txt))?$` with case-insensitive flag

Comment: That works for all the test cases I've tried - thank you.  I can't mark the comment as as answer but I'm happy with this as an accepted answer. [link to tests](https://regex101.com/r/ZmquQS/1)

Comment: I added my comment as an answer and added much more detail including better and more efficient patterns. I suggest using the last patterns in my answer if possible (or a variation based on the substitutes list) of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to match extensions?

As I mentioned in my original comment, your regex is well-formed; you just need to add an optional group for the extensions: `(\.(md|txt))?`

I also switched the order of the first two groups to make it more efficient (prevents unneeded backtracking if no `-` is found)

The regex below adds this logic to your pattern. I also removed the capture group surrounding the entire pattern as it's not necessary. If you want, you can always use the second pattern to get each part into a different group. If you don't need any groups, use the third pattern below (assuming your regex engine supports non-capture groups), and if you require two groups: one for the extension and one for the filename, use the fourth pattern below (with the same assumption):

```
# 1 - minimally changed original pattern
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+-)*[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.(md|txt))?$

# 2 - filename parts into groups
^(([a-zA-Z0-9]+-)*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\.(md|txt))?$

# 3 - no captures
^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+-)*[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\.(?:md|txt))?$

# 4 - filename and extension in groups
^((?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+-)*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\.(?:md|txt))?$        # captures .ext in 2nd group
^((?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+-)*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:\.(md|txt))?$        # captures ext in 2nd group
```

#### How to make it shorter?

Additionally, you can substitute `[a-zA-Z0-9]` for the following character sets in some regex engines:

```
# any letter in range a-z or any digit
# use case-insensitive flag to also match A-Z
[a-z\d]

# any character that's not not a word, and not _
# in other words, any word character ([a-zA-Z0-9_]) except _ ; so `[a-zA-Z0-9]`
[^\W_]
```

Shortest pattern:

```
^([^\W_]-?)*[^\W_](\.(md|txt))?$
```

---

#### How to make it more efficient?

Most efficient pattern (you can use any of the character class substitutions without changing the number of steps that this pattern takes to complete - I defaulted it to the shortest version of `[^\W_]`):

```
^([^\W_]+-)*[^\W_]+(\.(md|txt))?$

# if your regex engine accepts possessive quantifiers, use this to prevent backtracking
^([^\W_]+-)*+[^\W_]++(\.(md|txt))?$
           ^^      ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
(^([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)$|^([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+\.(txt|md))$)
```

Comment: This fails to invalidate non-matching patterns as described by OP.